# What are the advantages of the Property keyword in VB.NET over using a Private field with getters and setters?

Tags: vb.net, oop, design-patterns, properties

In VB.NET, what are the advantages of using the `Property` keyword rather than:

```
Private MyProperty as String
Public Sub setP(ByVal s as String)
    MyProperty = s
End Function
Public Function getP() as String
    return MyProperty
End Function
```

Coming from Java I tend to use this style rather than `Property...End Property` - is there any reason not to?

Comment: Yes, there's *every* reason not to. Properties are idiomatic .NET constructs. Don't write Java code in VB.NET (or C#, for that matter). If you want to write Java code, write code in Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing the work that the compiler does.  Advantages of the Property keyword:

- You can't accidentally mix up the getter and setter property type, a real issue in VB
- No need for the awkward *get* and *set* prefixes, the compiler figures out which one you want
- Data binding requires a property
- You can take advantage of the auto property syntax, no need to declare the private field and only a single line of code.

The same declaration in VS2010 using the auto property syntax:

```
Public Property P As String
```

The compiler auto-generates the getter and setter methods and the private backing field.  You refactor the accessors when necessary.

Comment: Hi Hans. This is only tangentially related, but are there any cases where would one want to generate a "smart property" that is private as opposed to just a private field? i.e. Is there any case where you would use `Private Property whatever As whatever` or even `Private Property ....` *with* an explicit getter and setter? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You will get some added benefits from properties that you will not get from using getters and setters.

Like reflection will find all your properties easily because there are methods for that.

ORM's for instance will easily be able to find your properties but it will be harder for them to find the getters setters because the convention is to use the properties.

So functionally they might be the same but the convention is to use properties.

Comment: Good point. Plus if using XAML the bindings become much easiler with Properties.

Answer (score 2):

Functionally there is no difference but for me the usage of Properties is a cleaner implementation. Look [here](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/rajeshvs/PropertiesInVbDotNet04192005060237AM/PropertiesInVbDotNet.aspx)

.Net 4 also gives AutoImplement proeprties to VB.net [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) wher ethe private backing variable is automatically created by the compiler resulting in much cleaner code and less boiler plate code to write.

Answer (score 2):

Using Properties makes the visual studio editor able to show/edit it in the property grid. If you are creating a control or dll that other will use they are used to be able to change design-time properties in the property-grid.

Also the [property-grid-control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) will be able to pick that up if you add the control to the form and then set the SelectedObject-property of the grid to an instance of your class/control.