# VB.NET MVC ViewModel Get and Set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, viewmodel, c#-to-vb.net

If a model has declared a string in C# as such:

```
public string Message { get; set; }
```

And I use the C# to VB.net [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/), my string now becomes:

```
Public Property Message() As String
    Get
        Return m_Message
    End Get
    Set
        m_Message = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Message As String
```

That is too many lines of code I would like to avoid for declaring a string.  If I have 50 strings in a viewmodel, it becomes to bulky.

This works in VB.net:

```
 Public Property Message() As String
```

Does declaring the string this way handle the get; set; by default?  Are there any pros or cons for ether VB.net examples I provided?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080774/what-are-the-advantages-of-the-property-keyword-in-vb-net-over-using-a-private-f - I'll use the more verbose way of defining a property if I need to do something out of the norm, such as adding a parameter to the getter or setter, which even then I'll usually just make a separate method for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shorter form is called `auto-implemented properties`, and basically works the same way as the longer method.  The compiler does the extra work behind the scenes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx